# Android Equivalent to iOS Enterprise Development

Tags: android, html, ios, cordova

I've slowly converting an iOS phonegap app I have to work with Android devices. One of my main concerns is how we deploy the app to both iOS device and Android. With iOS, my company is signed up for the enterprise developer account so we can host our in-house app ourselves, but I'm not sure if this is an option when working with Android. 

So I guess my question is, is it possible to host Android apps off your own server the same way you do with iOS Enterprise? If so, how would I go about this or where can I find more information on it?

Comment: I would assume it's even easier with Android

Comment: You don't even need an account at all to install *any* package on *any* android device.  You just need to make sure that untrusted sources are allowed in the settings.

Comment: And the untrusted sources would be associated with the device or is this in the apps settings? I honestly have never worked with android or even used an android phone so this is all new to me haha.

Comment: The "Allow Unknown Sources" option is located in the Security menu of each individual device (May also be in Developer Options)